# for python how can i use my application's console to execute one of my commands

Tags: python, string, function, console

I apologize if I didn't explain this well enough but I want to know how I could use my console in my app to take an input like "add 5 4" so it would actually add 5+4 instead of just printing it out. I really just need a function that could take the string "add 5 4" and recognize i started with the word add.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a fully-fledged interpreter, I would say learn [pyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Otherwise,

```
def parse(string):
    words = string.rsplit()
    if words[0] == "add":
        print int(word[1]) + int(word[2])

parse(raw_input());
```

Notice that I'm doing absolutely no error checking, you should have that in your app.

Comment: I would also suggest this (if you are really serious about writing something large): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler